# Remove ramifications/nerves from binary images in road detection

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-processing

I'm working on road detection project in aerial images using OpenCV with C++.
After some process I designed, I found a situation that I'm not sure if it is possible to do with OpenCV. (I have hit a raodblock)

**Here is my process.**
[Aerial Image of Road: RGB] -> [dilate: GrayScale] ->[thesh: Binary] -> [Zhang-Suen thinning: Binary] ->[dilate: Binary]->[findContour] ->[draw and fill Contour]->[Zhang-Suen thinning: Binary]

Original Image
[is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqSNw.jpg)

The last process result: Zhang-Suen thinning
[is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbjjl.jpg)

**I need help here**

As you might see, the last images have ramifications that I need to **delete** (I mean, **the lines surrounded by the red curves**). I just want to keep the main line that represent the road (In this case, 2 main roads, the 2 largest lines).
*The red indicators are not part of the project but they are just for explanation.*
[present here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QJ7G.jpg)

**Question**

1. Is there an algorithm into OpenCV that might help me?
2. How can I do this?
3. Could you help me with some algorithm?

I've being working in many algorithms looking for pixel and trying to delete them but I found me in many stackoverflow algorithms.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you upload the images you have mentioned in the question? I am unable to open the link you have mentioned. It says cannot open secure connection